# Converting XML document into an IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, rest

I have an XML document that i have deserialized according to my model class, now i want to convert it into an `IEnumerable<XmlDocument>` or `IEnumerable<string>` which is the return type of my function so i could return valid XML reply from my MVC REST API.

```
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.LoadXml(responseStream);
        XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(mSchoolModel));
        mSchoolModel mgp = (mSchoolModel)x.Deserialize(responseObj.GetResponseStream());
        //return xml;
```

So can anyone help me how can i convert this into an `IEnumerable`?

Comment: I might be missing something, but how are the first 2 lines of code related to the second 2? What is `responseObj`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the LINQ-to-XML API.

1. Convert your `XmlDocument` instance to an `XDocument` instance.  Instructions available at: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xmlteam/archive/2009/03/31/converting-from-xmldocument-to-xdocument.aspx
2. Use the [`Elements()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342765.aspx) or [`Descendants()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.descendants(v=vs.110).aspx) methods on the `XDocument` instance to get an `IEnumerable<XElement>`
3. Transform the `IEnumerable<XElement>` to an `IEnumerable<string>` using the LINQ [`Enumerable.Select()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx) operator.

Here's a simple example:

```
IEnumerable<string> elements 
  = XDocument
    .Load(new XmlNodeReader(xml))
    .Elements()
    .Select(element => element.ToString());
```

*Note: since a valid XML document can only have one root node, the resulting collection from the example above won't be very interesting, but you should have enough here to get what it is that you need.  If you're familiar with XPath, you may find it easier to get the elements you want using the XPath extensions to LINQ to XML.  See: [How To: Query LINQ to XML Using XPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387057.aspx)

### Update

Realized I may have read your question wrong.  If you have an `XmlDocument` instance and you need to return an `IEnumerable<XmlDocument>` all you have to do is wrap the instance in a collection.  For example,

```
 IEnumerable<XmlDocument> xmlCollection = new XmlDocument[]{ xml };
```

Of course, this approach can be used for wrapping any object into a singleton collection of objects of the same type.